# android google drive api cannot query folder

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

All files are in the MetadataBuffer,but folder not included.

```
            Tasks.await(driveClient.requestSync());
            Query q = new Query.Builder()
                    .addFilter(Filters.in(SearchableField.PARENTS, rootFolder.getDriveId()))
                    .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false))
                    .build();
            Task<MetadataBuffer> queryTask = driveResourceClient.query(q);
            MetadataBuffer query = Tasks.await(queryTask);
            for (int i = 0; i < query.getCount(); i++) {
                Log.d(TAG, query.get(i).getTitle());
            }
```

how to list children folder as well?

I have try .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "application/vnd.google-apps.folder")) already, doesn't work too..

Thanks